# Properly Serializing A Class in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm very new to the .NET framework, I'm attempting to serialize a class in the following namespace so that messages can be returned from a server to a client application. I do not have access to Visual Studio or any other IDE that supports .NET, unfortunately, and not able to install anything on the machine without approval. But, I'm thinking the syntax or declaration is messing up somewhere. Here is what I have, so far.

```
namespace ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks
{
  [Serializable]
  public class GPMessage  
  {
    public string Description {get;}
    public GPMessageType MessageType {get;}
  }
}
```

Obviously, something is not working correctly.

Here is the library reference : https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/api-reference/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPMessage.html

I also tried:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks
{
  [Serializable]
  public class GPMessage  
  {
    public string Description {get;}
    public GPMessageType MessageType {get;}
  }
}
```

I'm receiving an error response:

> Unhandled exception: '} expected Invalid token 'namespace' in class,
>   struct, or interface member declaration Invalid token '{' in class,
>   struct, or interface member declaration Type or namespace definition,
>   or end-of-file expected

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of format do you want ? XML, JSON, Binary ?

Comment: Why no access to an IDE?  Visual Studio Community is free, (as is Code, though I much prefer VS myself)

Comment: Are you aware of [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)? It's a free, open source cross-platform IDE from Microsoft. If you can install applications on your computer, you can use it to use features like code completion, syntax highlighting, debugging etc. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp)'s an article that shows you how to use it with C#. **Edit:** Seems like @jdl134679 was a bit faster than me!

Comment: Hi, x... I'm trying to return messages in string format. The GPMessage has a description and messagetype property. I'm trying to serialize the entire class so that its properties can be accessed as string and displayed in the client application in a dialog box, here is the API https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/api-reference/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPMessage.html

Comment: We're unable to install anything on our machine without IT approval :(

Comment: I don't see any particular issue with the class.  What's the code you're trying to use to serialize? (lack of a setter shouldn't affect the ability to serialize, only to deserialize)

Comment: jdl, thanks for your input. I provided a link to the API in the main post. I'm receiving a message saying it cannot be serialized. Does a Data contract attribute need to be used, and each property assigned as a Data Member ?

Answer (score 0):

You get better control of the serialization and deeper understanding using an API like BinaryFormatter. Here is some code I found from a personal project I worked on some time ago. Pay close attention to Load/Save and also the serialization constructor used to recreate a class as well as the GetObjectData call which packs the data in a way that the BinaryFormatter can use to go "to and from" binary data and in my case eventually write the bytes to a file. What you want is to write the data to a String from Byte array. Remember the class needs a constructor that takes the same params as GetObjectData. Think of it as "Load" calls this constructor to load the class and "Save" calls GetObjectData to save the class. This makes since given that you would need a constructor to handle loading the data. Also, I use a FileStream but the BinaryFormatter API just wants any Stream so you can use a StringReader/Writer or MemoryStream for your purposes without needing disk access.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.IO;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Genesis.Windows.Desktop.Account
{
    [Serializable]
    internal class UserSettings : ISerializable
    {
        public String AccountId { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        internal String _password = "";
    public String Password 
    {
        get
        {
            return Security.ValueSecurity.DecryptString(_password, MainWindow.ApplicationId);
        }
        set
        {
            string password = value;
            if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                password = Security.ValueSecurity.EncryptString(value, MainWindow.ApplicationId);
            _password = password;
        }
    }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    public Genesis.Portal.Controllers.API.AuthToken AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
    public String WebAPIUrl = "https://127.0.0.1/API/";

    // Outlook
    public bool IsOutlookSyncReady { get; set; }
    public List<String> OutlookAccounts { get; set; }
    public String OutlookCalendarFolderName { get; set; }
    public string OutlookCalendarFolderId { get; set; }
    public string OutlookProfileName { get; set; }

    // GMail
    public bool IsGMailSyncReady { get; set; }
    public String GMailToken { get; set; }
    public String GMailCalendarFolderName { get; set; }        

    // PIM Calendar Sync
    public DateTime LastCalendarSyncDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalCalendarRecords { get; set; }
    public int LastCalendarAddCount { get; set; }
    public int LastCalendarEditCount { get; set; }
    public int LastCalendarDeleteCount { get; set; }

    // PIM Tasks Sync
    public DateTime LastTasksSyncDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalTaskRecords { get; set; }
    public int LastTasksAddCount { get; set; }
    public int LastTasksEditCount { get; set; }
    public int LastTasksDeleteCount { get; set; }

    // PIM Email Sync
    public DateTime LastEmailSyncDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalEmailRecords { get; set; }
    public int LastEmailAddCount { get; set; }
    public int LastEmailEditCount { get; set; }
    public int LastEmailDeleteCount { get; set; }

    // PIM Contacts Sync
    public DateTime LastContactsSyncDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalContactsRecords { get; set; }
    public int LastContactsAddCount { get; set; }
    public int LastContactsEditCount { get; set; }
    public int LastContactsDeleteCount { get; set; }

    public UserSettings()
    {
        this.AccountId = "";
        this.Email = "";
        this.GMailCalendarFolderName = "My Case Folder";
        this.GMailToken = "";
        this.IsGMailSyncReady = false;
        this.IsOutlookSyncReady = false;
        this.OutlookAccounts = new List<String>();
        this.OutlookCalendarFolderName = "My Case Folder";
        this.OutlookCalendarFolderId = null;
        this.OutlookProfileName = ""; // Not Known
        this.Password = "";
        this.RememberMe = false;

        LastCalendarSyncDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900"); // Using history will trigger a sync on first run.
        LastCalendarAddCount = 0;
        LastCalendarDeleteCount = 0;
        LastCalendarEditCount = 0;
        TotalCalendarRecords = 0;

        LastTasksSyncDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900"); // Using history will trigger a sync on first run.
        LastTasksAddCount = 0;
        LastTasksEditCount = 0;
        LastTasksDeleteCount = 0;
        TotalTaskRecords = 0;

        LastEmailSyncDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900"); // Using history will trigger a sync on first run.
        LastEmailAddCount = 0;
        LastEmailDeleteCount = 0;
        LastEmailEditCount = 0;
        TotalEmailRecords = 0;

        LastContactsSyncDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900"); // Using history will trigger a sync on first run.
        LastContactsAddCount = 0;
        LastContactsDeleteCount = 0;
        LastContactsEditCount = 0;
        TotalContactsRecords = 0;

    }

    public UserSettings(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.AccountId = info.GetString("AccountId");
        this.Email = info.GetString("Email");
        this.GMailCalendarFolderName = info.GetString("GMailCalendarFolderName");
        this.GMailToken = info.GetString("GMailToken");
        this.IsGMailSyncReady = info.GetBoolean("IsGMailSyncReady");
        this.IsOutlookSyncReady = info.GetBoolean("IsOutlookSyncReady");
        this.OutlookCalendarFolderName = info.GetString("OutlookCalendarFolderName");
        this._password = info.GetString("Password");
        this.RememberMe = info.GetBoolean("RememberMe");

        this.LastCalendarSyncDate = info.GetDateTime("LastCalendarSyncDate");  
        this.LastTasksSyncDate = info.GetDateTime("LastTasksSyncDate");  
        this.LastContactsSyncDate = info.GetDateTime("LastCalendarSyncDate");  
        this.LastEmailSyncDate = info.GetDateTime("LastEmailSyncDate");
        this.OutlookProfileName = info.GetString("OutlookProfileName"); 

        LastCalendarAddCount = info.GetInt32("LastCalendarAddCount");
        LastCalendarDeleteCount = info.GetInt32("LastCalendarDeleteCount");
        LastCalendarEditCount = info.GetInt32("LastCalendarEditCount");
        TotalCalendarRecords = info.GetInt32("TotalCalendarRecords");
        LastTasksAddCount = info.GetInt32("LastTasksAddCount");
        LastTasksEditCount = info.GetInt32("LastTasksEditCount");
        LastTasksDeleteCount = info.GetInt32("LastTasksDeleteCount");
        TotalTaskRecords = info.GetInt32("TotalTaskRecords");
        LastEmailAddCount = info.GetInt32("LastEmailAddCount");
        LastEmailDeleteCount = info.GetInt32("LastEmailDeleteCount");
        LastEmailEditCount = info.GetInt32("LastEmailEditCount");
        TotalEmailRecords = info.GetInt32("TotalEmailRecords");
        LastContactsAddCount = info.GetInt32("LastContactsAddCount");
        LastContactsDeleteCount = info.GetInt32("LastContactsDeleteCount");
        LastContactsEditCount = info.GetInt32("LastContactsEditCount");
        TotalContactsRecords = info.GetInt32("TotalContactsRecords");
        WebAPIUrl = info.GetString("WebAPIUrl");

        this.OutlookAccounts = new List<String>();
        int outlookAcountsCount = info.GetInt16("outlookAcountsCount");
        for (int i = 0; i < outlookAcountsCount; i++ )
                this.OutlookAccounts.Add(info.GetString("OutlookAccount["+i.ToString()+"]"));

        try
        {
            this.OutlookCalendarFolderId = info.GetString("OutlookCalendarFolderId");
        }
        catch (Exception) {/*Not supported in all versions*/}

    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("LastCalendarSyncDate", this.LastCalendarSyncDate);
        info.AddValue("LastTasksSyncDate", this.LastTasksSyncDate);
        info.AddValue("LastContactsSyncDate", this.LastContactsSyncDate);
        info.AddValue("LastEmailSyncDate", this.LastEmailSyncDate);

        info.AddValue("AccountId",  this.AccountId);
        info.AddValue("Email", this.Email);
        info.AddValue("GMailCalendarFolderName", this.GMailCalendarFolderName);
        info.AddValue("GMailToken", this.GMailToken);
        info.AddValue("IsGMailSyncReady", this.IsGMailSyncReady);
        info.AddValue("IsOutlookSyncReady", this.IsOutlookSyncReady);
        info.AddValue("OutlookCalendarFolderName", this.OutlookCalendarFolderName);
        info.AddValue("Password", this._password);
        info.AddValue("RememberMe", this.RememberMe);
        info.AddValue("OutlookProfileName", this.OutlookProfileName); 

        info.AddValue("LastCalendarAddCount", LastCalendarAddCount);
        info.AddValue("LastCalendarDeleteCount", LastCalendarDeleteCount);
        info.AddValue("LastCalendarEditCount", LastCalendarEditCount);
        info.AddValue("TotalCalendarRecords", TotalCalendarRecords);
        info.AddValue("LastTasksAddCount", LastTasksAddCount);
        info.AddValue("LastTasksEditCount", LastTasksEditCount);
        info.AddValue("LastTasksDeleteCount", LastTasksDeleteCount);
        info.AddValue("TotalTaskRecords", TotalTaskRecords);
        info.AddValue("LastEmailAddCount", LastEmailAddCount);
        info.AddValue("LastEmailDeleteCount", LastEmailDeleteCount);
        info.AddValue("LastEmailEditCount",LastEmailEditCount);
        info.AddValue("TotalEmailRecords",TotalEmailRecords);
        info.AddValue("LastContactsAddCount",LastContactsAddCount);
        info.AddValue("LastContactsDeleteCount",LastContactsDeleteCount);
        info.AddValue("LastContactsEditCount",LastContactsEditCount);
        info.AddValue("TotalContactsRecords",TotalContactsRecords);
        info.AddValue("WebAPIUrl", WebAPIUrl);

        info.AddValue("outlookAcountsCount", this.OutlookAccounts.Count);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (String account in this.OutlookAccounts)
        {
            info.AddValue("OutlookAccount[" + i.ToString() + "]", account);
            i++;
        }

        try
        {
            if(this.OutlookCalendarFolderId != null)
                info.AddValue("OutlookCalendarFolderId", this.OutlookCalendarFolderId);
        }
        catch (Exception) {/*Not supported in all versions*/}
    }

    internal static void Save(UserSettings file)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file.FilePath))
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog saveFolder = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (saveFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;
            file.FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(saveFolder.SelectedPath, "User.settings");
        }

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FilePath, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, file);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }

    internal static UserSettings Load(String filePath)
    {
        UserSettings file = null;
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            file = new UserSettings();
            file.FilePath = filePath;
            UserSettings.Save(file);
        }
        else
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                file = (UserSettings)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
                file.FilePath = filePath;
            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        return file;
    }

    internal static void Clear(string file)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
        }
    }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

}
```

}